# How to load (indexing) json file using elasticsearch and nodejs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm reading [the nodejs elasticsearch doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/introduction.html), and it's show in the example that they index 3 samples only, but I want to index or load a json file that contain like 1000 docs, can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by:

```
//initialize the client
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch')
const client = new Client({ node: 'http://localhost:9200' })

// to read json files
var fs = require('fs');
/ Start reading the json file
fs.readFile('DocRes.json', {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
  
    // Build up a giant bulk request for elasticsearch.
    bulk_request = data.split('\n').reduce(function(bulk_request, line) {
      var obj, ncar;
  
      try {
        obj = JSON.parse(line);
      } catch(e) {
        console.log('Done reading 1');
        return bulk_request;
      }
  
      // Rework the data slightly
      ncar = {
        id: obj.id,
        name: obj.name,
        summary: obj.summary,
        image: obj.image,
        approvetool: obj.approvetool,
        num: obj.num, 
        date: obj.date,
      };
  
      bulk_request.push({index: {_index: 'ncar_index', _type: 'ncar', _id: ncar.id}});
      bulk_request.push(ncar);
      return bulk_request;
    }, []);
  
    // A little voodoo to simulate synchronous insert
    var busy = false;
    var callback = function(err, resp) {
      if (err) { console.log(err); }
  
      busy = false;
    };
  
    // Recursively whittle away at bulk_request, 1000 at a time.
    var perhaps_insert = function(){
      if (!busy) {
        busy = true;
        client.bulk({
          body: bulk_request.slice(0, 1000)
        }, callback);
        bulk_request = bulk_request.slice(1000);
        console.log(bulk_request.length);
      }
  
      if (bulk_request.length > 0) {
        setTimeout(perhaps_insert, 100);
      } else {
        console.log('Inserted all records.');
      }
    };
  
    perhaps_insert();
  });
```